# How to assess a dose-response relationship in regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

If I have a fixed effects regression model over time and across 20 different  individuals (actual human beings) as follows:

```
Model Formula: freeradicals ~ metabolicox + exercise

Coefficients:
 metabolicox          exercise
 0.25                 1.011
```

My interpretation of this therfore is that for every 1 unit rise in the `metabolicox` variable I get a 0.25 unit rise in the `freeradicals` while holding `excercise` constant. Similarly, for every 1 unit rise in the `exercise` variable I get a ~1 unit rise in the `freeradicals` while holding `metabolicox` constant.

My question therefore is: how can I assess whether the dose-response relationship between these unit rises? Do I have to do several regressions while multiplying the independent variable of interest by some constant. For example, I could change the formula to:

```
Model Formula: freeradicals ~ 2*metabolicox + exercise
```

which would assess how a doubling in `metabolicox` works, and then do that for different constants from 2 up to 10 in increments of 1 for example.

Comment: Your interpretations appear to be backward. A coefficient of 0.25 on metabolicox with the formula that way around means for every 1 unit rise in the `metabolicox` variable you get a 0.25 unit rise in `freeradicals`.

Comment: Sorry yes I'll correct that. Is there anyway to assess dose response then?

Comment: Also what are the units? Do they have to be the same for the independent and dependent variables? If I have metabolicox as a in joules and  freeradicals as a percentage, how do I interpret this in terms of the respective units?

Comment: The coefficient will have units of the ratio of the units involved so that $\beta_ix_i$ is in units of $y$; i.e. the coefficient of $x_i$ will have units of $\frac{\text{units of }x_i}{\text{units of }y}$.

Comment: Thanks for generalizing. So that means for every 1 joule of `metabolicox` I'll get 0.25 percent increase in `freeradicals`?

Comment: 1. If metabilicox is in joules and freeradicals is in percent, that's how the units work, yes. However ... $\quad$ $\quad$ $\:$ 2. That's the estimated *expected* change under the model, not the actual change for any particular outcome. $\!$ 3. You seem to have gone from a regression model to a causal statement, there; generally you can't do that (which makes the wording of such interpretations tricky).

Comment: @Glen_b thanks any idea on assessing dose response, which would help me assert causation instead of just association?

Comment: If you have a proper experiment, then it's the experimental setup that (potentially) allows you to assert causality -- if you control for any other possible explanatory variables (or at least control for some and are able to randomize the others out), you have grounds for a causal argument. The numbers themselves don't give you that, they simply tell you what the relationship is once you've established causality rather than simple association. But if you could have other variables there (as you might with an observational study) then you may have trouble arguing that the relationship is causal